# Relate indices where two dataframes are equal with elements in another array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, vectorization

I have an array `cluster_true` and a dataframe `data` containing in each row a 2D coordinate. I want to save in another dataframe information regarding how many times for a given 2D coordinate each element in `cluster_true` appeared. So, for instance, for the coordinate (1,1), I want to check all the rows in `data` whose first two columns have the value of `1`, and then check the values of `cluster_true` at those indices. Here is an example to make it clearer (it gives the desired result):

```
# Example variables
cluster_true = c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1)
x = 3
y = 3
data = data.frame(X = c(1,1,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1),
                  Y = c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,0))

# Names of the columns
plot_colnames = c('X', 'Y', paste('cluster',unique(cluster_true),sep='_'))
# Empty dataframe with the right column names
plot_df = data.frame(matrix(vector(), x*y, length(plot_colnames),
                            dimnames=list(c(), plot_colnames)),
                     stringsAsFactors=F)
# Each row belongs to a certain 2D coordinate
plot_df$X = rep(1:x, y)-1
plot_df$Y = rep(1:x, each = y)-1
# This is what I don't know how to improve
for(i in 1:nrow(plot_df)){
  idx = which(apply(data[,1:2], 1, function(x) all(x == plot_df[i,1:2])))
  plot_df[i,3] = sum(cluster_true[idx] == 1)
  plot_df[i,4] = sum(cluster_true[idx] == 2)
}
print(plot_df)
```

Things I need to change and I don't know how to:

- I think the loop could be avoided in order to get a more elegant solution, but I don't know how. The dataframe `data` could have a very large amount of rows, so efficient code would be awesome.
- Inside the loop, I've hardcoded the clusters to check (the last two lines inside the loop assume that I know which numbers are present in `cluster_true` and to which column of `plot_df` they correspond to). In fact, the elements in `cluster_true` could be anything, even non-consecutive numbers (i.e. `cluster_true = c(1,5,5,5,56,10,19,10)`).

So basically, I want to know if this could be done without the loop and as generic as possible.

Comment: Is it intended that the coordinates (1,3), (2,2), and (3, 1) which appear in `data` are missing from `plot_df`?

Comment: @Uwe Sorry about that, I had given the variable `y` the wrong value. I've corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to

- find the row indices for all unique combinations of `X, Y` coordinates in `data`,
- look up the value in the corresponding rows of `cluster_true`,
- count the number of occurrences of each value for the given `X, Y` combination, and
- print the results in wide format.

This can be solved by joining and reshaping:

```
library(data.table) # version 1.11.4 used
library(magrittr)   # use piping to improve readability
# unique coordinate pairs
uni_coords <- unique(setDT(data)[, .(X, Y)])[order(X, Y)]
# join and lookup values in cluster_true
data[uni_coords, on = .(X, Y), cluster_true[.I], by = .EACHI] %>% 
  # reshape from long to wide format, thereby counting occurrences
  dcast(X + Y ~ sprintf("cluster_%02i", V1), length)
```

> ```
>    X Y cluster_01 cluster_02
> 1: 1 1          2          1
> 2: 1 2          1          1
> 3: 1 3          1          1
> 4: 2 2          0          1
> 5: 3 1          1          0
> 6: 3 2          1          0
> 7: 3 3          0          3
> ```

This is identical with OP's expected result except for the coordinate combinations which do not appear in `data`.

```
setDT(plot_df)[order(X, Y)]
```

> ```
>    X Y cluster_1 cluster_2
> 1: 1 1         2         1
> 2: 1 2         1         1
> 3: 1 3         1         1
> 4: 2 1         0         0
> 5: 2 2         0         1
> 6: 2 3         0         0
> 7: 3 1         1         0
> 8: 3 2         1         0
> 9: 3 3         0         3
> ```

Reshaping has the benefit that it can handle arbitrary values in `cluster_true` as requested by the OP.

#### Edit

The OP [has requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355542/relate-indices-where-two-dataframes-are-equal-with-elements-in-another-array/52356678?noredirect=1#comment91691645_52356678) that all *possible* combinations of `X, Y` coordinates should be included in the final result. This can be achieved by using a *cross join* `CJ()` to compute `uni_coords`:

```
# all possible  coordinate pairs
uni_coords <- setDT(data)[, CJ(X = X, Y = Y, unique = TRUE)]
# join and lookup values in cluster_true
data[uni_coords, on = .(X, Y), cluster_true[.I], by = .EACHI][
  uni_coords, on = .(X, Y)] %>% 
  # reshape from long to wide format, thereby counting occurrences
  dcast(X + Y ~ sprintf("cluster_%02i", V1), length) %>% 
  # remove NA column from reshaped result
  .[, cluster_NA := NULL] %>% 
  print()
```

> ```
>    X Y cluster_01 cluster_02
> 1: 1 1          2          1
> 2: 1 2          1          1
> 3: 1 3          1          1
> 4: 2 1          0          0
> 5: 2 2          0          1
> 6: 2 3          0          0
> 7: 3 1          1          0
> 8: 3 2          1          0
> 9: 3 3          0          3
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you could add how to get the missing rows in the final result (i.e. get to the second dataframe in your post from the first one), this would indeed be the accepted answer.